# Why are files opening in a second pane from 'find results 1'?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using vs.net 2012, and when I search for a string in the entire solution, in my find results pane, when I click on a file, it opens the file in the bottom pane.  It used to open 'normally' in the top pane where all my other source files are.

What did I do to get vs.net to mess with my mind? :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You probably *docked* the `Find Results` as a *content window* instead of a *tool pane*.
So now actually have two document panes, one of which contains the `Find Results`.

When you open a new document (In your example - double-clicking it from the Find Results), it automatically opens in the last focused document pane, which in your case is the one containing the Find Results.

To fix this, re-dock the Find Results in Far-Bottom  (or, in the image below the far-right for instance)

[image]

Comment: +1 (VS 2017) For me, I had to pull all the tabs out of the docked window into a floating window and then dock all of them together into a tool pane.