# How can I change the default window where Visual Studio opens / docks new windows?

Tags: visual-studio, layout, window

I have what seems to be an unusual layout for Visual Studio 2015 whereby the find results, exception settings, breakpoints, error list, etc. panels are docked together in one separate window that I keep on a second monitor so that they're all visible without having to click on tabs to access them and so that they don't clutter up my view of the main window where I keep my code files open.

The problem is that whenever visual studio decides to open a new file, for example when selecting a result in the find results panel or a line in the call stack panel, it opens it in the most inconvenient of places such as as a new tab in the breakpoints panel, which is a rather small rectangle on my screen. How can I force Visual Studio to always open the new windows on my main tab where my code files are usually opened?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaG71.png) is an image with a screenshot of my layout and the problem. I masked the class names because of confidentiality and all that. Also, I decreased the size of the window for the sake of this question but I usually keep it maximized on one of the screens.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992480/why-are-files-opening-in-a-second-pane-from-find-results-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot, your Breakpoints, Task List and Exception Settings windows are **Docked as Tabbed Document**. That is why normal document tabs are opened near them.

You need to **Dock** these windows as your Find results1, Output and Error List windows to prevent the problem.

Comment: Thanks! That's a... very interesting UI design choice since those aren't exactly what I would call documents. It was also really finicky to do the layout without making those tabbed documents.

Comment: It would be nice if you could "lock" a docking section so nothing new could be opened there. Or be able to set properties in a tab and select a target for opening new tabs spawned from that tab.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to reset Visual studio Environment settings Click Tool->Import and export settingn->Reset settings, Don't worry it won't mess up with your project

Comment: That resets my layout as well which is not what I want. I want to keep using this layout. Anyway, I did the reset, laid out my windows as I want them again and the issue persists.